# compare two datetime by Date and Time in dynamic query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, compare

I'm trying to compare two datetime but it doesnt work in dynamic query.
why portion of time doesnt work?
my codes are these

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testdate]    
    @startDate datetime = null  ,
    @endDate datetime = null,
    @TableName nvarchar(100) ,
    @SearchString NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    declare @sqlcmd nvarchar(max)


    set  @sqlcmd= 'select * from '+@TableName  +' where '   
    if @startDate is not null and @endDate is not null
    begin

        /*set @sqlcmd=@sqlcmd + ' ( DateLog between'''
        + convert (nvarchar(50), @startDate, 101)
        +''' and ''' 
        --+ convert (nvarchar(50),DATEADD(D,1, @endDate), 101)
        + convert (nvarchar(50), @endDate, 101)
        + ''' ) and '   
        */
        set @sqlcmd=@sqlcmd + ' ( DateLog between @startDate and @endDate ) and '

    end     


    set @sqlcmd=@sqlcmd + '('
    SELECT 
            @sqlcmd  = @sqlcmd + '  [' + SYSCOLUMNS.NAME + '] LIKE N''%'+@SearchString+'%'' or '    
            FROM SYSCOLUMNS 
            WHERE OBJECT_NAME(id) =  @TableName AND TYPE_NAME(SYSCOLUMNS.XTYPE) IN ('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR','CHAR','NCHAR','INT','DECIMAL')

        set @sqlcmd  = @sqlcmd  + '1<>1)'                           
    --print @sqlcmd                                             
    Exec(@sqlcmd)
END
```

my table AccountLog have  these fields and datas

```
     UserName     DateLog
     Salah        2012-04-06 22:06:19.493
     John         2012-08-06 22:06:22.800
```

this query is true

```
 select * from AccountLog where DateLog between '2012-04-06T22:06:19' and '2012-08-06T22:06:23'
```

but this query does not give me  the appropriate result

```
declare @a datetime
declare @b datetime 
set @a = '2012-04-06T22:06:19'  
set @b = '2012-08-06T22:06:23'
exec testdate @a,@b,'AccountLog',N'test'
```

Comment: why it is **2012-04-06T22:06:19** instead of **2012-04-06 22:06:19** ?

Comment: because of time portion if i dont use -(dash) it is not true

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Can you please do a PRINT @sql and see what does that give you?

Comment: because of so many tables. i have a another  field TableName that is input parameter

Comment: i have edited my procedure , please see my procedure a gain

Comment: What is the trailing `and` for? Where do you use `@SearchString`?

Comment: i dont have any problem with SearchString. SearchString is a parameter that use after converting datetime.my problem is converting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing date and time in to your procedure, but when you convert those to dynamic SQL, you are using format 101, which removes the time portion.  Try changing the 101 to 126 (there are 2 places within your code where 101 is used, make sure you change both of them.

Answer (score 3):

You should use strong typed parameters and completely throw away any of this convert to nvarchar nonsense.

**EDIT** updated for yet more requirement changes.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testdate]    
  @startDate    DATETIME = NULL,
  @endDate      DATETIME = NULL,
  @TableName    NVARCHAR(100),
  @SearchString NVARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
  SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
    + ' WHERE (1 = 0 ';

  SELECT @sql = @sql + ' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' LIKE N''%'+@SearchString+'%'''  
    FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + @TableName)
    AND system_type_id IN (56,106,167,175,231,239);

  SET @sql = @sql + ')';

  IF @startDate IS NOT NULL AND @endDate IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND DateLog BETWEEN @s AND @e';
  END

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@s DATETIME, @e DATETIME', @startDate, @endDate;
END
GO
```

Comment: Aaron Bertrand your code is not correct u have this error with your code  Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".

Comment: @SalahSanjabian can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: What do you want to know more about?
 My codes are clear
 I have problem just with Date Time

Comment: Your initial comment did not include the actual error message. And if you copied the code exactly (not just a part of it), you shouldn't have gotten that error message.

Comment: ok,i have edited my code again, please see my code i used your code but i have a error that i mentioned in above comment

Comment: You should have *started* with the whole code if you don't have the capability to adapt the code that solves your stated problem to your actual problem. This creates a LOT less work for everyone involved. Anyway I don't see how you could have that error unless you didn't copy my code correctly or you didn't copy all of it. Can you show the ACTUAL CODE YOU ARE RUNNING to get that error, instead of just telling me kind of vaguely what you might have done?

Comment: You totally missed the point. And I wrote a whole stored procedure for you that should work and avoid the messy conversion from datetime to string, which isn't necessary.

Comment: Great, thanks. Remind me about this the next time I might have input on one of your questions. :-(